# Why am I getting an error using List.map in F#?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#

Why does the F# compiler complain "RequireQualifiedAccess ..." for the Open statement and give an error for the use of List.map in:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Map
type Gen = 
    static member Calc (data : int[]) = data.List.map (fun x -> x + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `open` statement has nothing to to with `List.map`, it would open the `Map` module, which you cannot open but have to access explicitly with `Map.`, hence the error. The `Map` module contains functions similar to the ones in the `List` module, but works with maps (similar to dictionaries in C#).

The function `List.map` ist just called that: `List.map`. It is standalone and not a part of your `data` object, which, by the way, you have defined to be an array with `(data : int[])`.

So I think the code you meant to write is:

```
type Gen =
    static member Calc (data : List<int>) = data |> List.map (fun x -> x + 1)
```

And also note that the compiler is smart enough to deduce that data is a list of ints, so you can remove the type annotation if you like.

Comment: When keeping the type annotation, it is advisable annotate F# lists in the alternative way: `(data : int list)`. There is a name collision between F#'s `List<'T>` and `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>`; by annotating F# lists via the lowercase type abbreviation, the code's meaning remain intact in case `System.Collections.Generic` is opened. *Also, otherwise, programmers reading the code may falsely assume the "ResizeArray" kind of list is meant when they see the annotation.*